# Javascript exporting class instance (React JS application)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a single page application using React JS, and following the Flux flow.

I have a problem where I want to export an instance of a class (an action class), import elsewhere, and then reference some of the class methods. I can import the class with no error, but when the class' methods are referenced it throws a "TypeError: undefined is not an object".

A console.log() confirms that that class is undefined, however I also import the action in another file. So I decided to console log it's reference to the action class and log where the export is happening.

What I found is that the first reference is still undefined, but before the second reference is called, the export happens and the second console.log() returns the object and it's methods.

So my question is, does javascript deal with exports as it comes across them, or does it do all the exports first?

Example of the code:

```
class Action {
    methodOne(){ ..... }
    methodTwo(){ ..... } 
}
const instance = new Action();
export default instance;
```

The action is then imported as:

```
import Action from '../actions/Action';
```

in the two files.

I have checked and double checked spelling and import paths which all seem to be correct. Some research does say that it could be something to do with circular references, though that doesn't seem to be obvious to me (not discounting it though).

I'm all out of ideas as to where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you might have a circular dependency between your modules. Write down the module names on a piece of paper and draw arrows between them.

Comment: Turns out that is the case.......Can't believe I couldn't see it on the screen and it took paper to see it. Now to resolve it.Thanks.

Comment: To be clear: A circular dependency is not necessarily bad, but it will be a problem if you are trying to access the imported value at "import time", which it seems like you do. If you can defer accessing the imported value then it wouldn't be a problem (which seems to be happening in the second module).